# How to translate an email snippet in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

My language is Brazilian Portuguese, and I'm having trouble translating a snippet of an email template that Laravel sends to the user. in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/ResetPassword` I managed to translate most of the template, but a snippet I couldn't, as I don't know where it is located.

[image]

I would like to know where is the location of the passages marked in red to translate in my language (i'm using Laravel Breeze application).

Comment: Don't edit files from the `/vendor/` folder, your changes will most likely get overwritten when a package is updated

Answer (score 0):

They can be translated in the JSON file in the lang directory (see [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization#using-translation-strings-as-keys)).

You can download a prefilled translation file here (just rename it to "pt-BR.json" and place it in the root lang path `/resources/lang/`): https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang/blob/main/locales/pt_BR/json.json

You're free to modify these translations as you wish.